# Android Payment Platform options circa 2012

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, payment, amazon-appstore

Is there any consensus on what the best payment apis are for use with Android and in app purchases?

Googling for 'Android payment api' there's tons of hits from, paypal, sms, to credit card companies, etc.  But most of those articles are years old.  Also, many articles refer to Google Checkout not being worldwide (those too are typically years old).

If you have experience on Android with in app purchases.

Is Google's In-App billing now the preferred way to handling billing in the Google Play Market?

I'm aware Amazon's store has a completely separate billing system.

Basically I'm asking circa 2012, has there been any convergence on in app purchase options for Android or is it still the wild west.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you release your application on Google Play, you should probably use Googles own [in-app billing APIs](http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/billing/index.html). The [Google Play Developer Program Policies](http://www.android.com/us/developer-content-policy.html) state that only authorized payment processors may provide in-app billing, but I don't think there is any official list of them. Therefore it's a bit unclear which ones Google will allow in the future, but using their own alternative should definitely be safe.